# Oracle - Copying table data from one schema to another schema

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I tried the following stored procedure for copying one table records from one schema table to another schema table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_DATA
AS
cursor C_BRIC_EXTRACT
is
select pend_date, pend_note, record_id, suspense_cd, suspense_date from DEV_SWIMLANE2.billing_record_invoiced_code;
BEGIN
FOR C_EXTRACT_BRIC_REC IN C_BRIC_EXTRACT
LOOP
 BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO
   DEV_ARCHIVE.BRIC_ARCHV(SUSPENSE_CD,RECORD_ID,SUSPENSE_DATE,PEND_DATE,PEND_NOTE)
  VALUES
   (C_EXTRACT_BRIC_REC.SUSPENSE_CD, C_EXTRACT_BRIC_REC.RECORD_ID, C_EXTRACT_BRIC_REC.SUSPENSE_DATE, C_EXTRACT_BRIC_REC.PEND_DATE, C_EXTRACT_BRIC_REC.PEND_NOTE);  
  COMMIT;
 END; 
END LOOP;
END;
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
17:20:27  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1031, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
 17:20:27  [BEGIN - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 8, column 159:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
 17:20:27  [COMMIT - 0 row(s), 0.293 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
 17:20:28  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
 17:20:29  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
 17:20:29  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Please help me how to set the privileges and also please let me know whether there is any issue on my stored procedure in oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a stored procedure and definitely not a cursor for this. It is **much** more efficient to do this with a single statement.

**Edit** to generate a unique value for the ARCHIVE_ID column, you should create a sequence:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ARCHIVE_ID;
```

and then use that in the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO DEV_ARCHIVE.BRIC_ARCHV 
   (ARCHIVE_ID, SUSPENSE_CD, RECORD_ID, SUSPENSE_DATE, PEND_DATE, PEND_NOTE)
select seq_archive_id.nextval, 
       suspense_cd, 
       record_id, 
       suspense_date, 
       pend_date, 
       pend_note
from DEV_SWIMLANE2.billing_record_invoiced_code;
COMMIT;
```

If you do want to have it in a stored procedure, you can put the above statement in one. But you should definitely get rid of the slow row-by-row inserts using the cursor. The fact that you commit each and every record makes this even worse.

Regarding your errors:

> *ORA-01031: insufficient privileges*

simply means that the user under which your procedure is execute either does not have the privilege to select from the source table or the user does not have the privilege to insert into the target table. You will need to make sure the necessary GRANTs have been given.

If you are logged in as the user `DEV_ARCHIVE` you can run:

```
GRANT INSERT ON BRIC_ARCHV TO DEV_SWIMLANE2;
```

to give the user DEV_SWIMLANE2 the privilege to insert into the target table.

or alternatively, if you are logged in as DEV_SWIMLANE2 you can run:

```
GRANT SELECT ON billing_record_invoiced_code TO DEV_ARCHIVE;
```

to give the user DEV_ARCHIVE the privilege to select from the source table. Which one you prefer is a matter of choice. I'd probably use the second version: giving the target user the privilege to read the source data.

Comment: Actually I am having a column named ARCHIVE_ID which is set to NOT NULL in BRIC_ARCHV table. How to get the value incremented in ARCHIVE_ID column for each and every record which will get inserted. Error is "Error Code: 1400, SQL State: 23000] ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DEV_ARCHIVE"."BRIC_ARCHV"."ARCHIVE_ID")"